# How do you combine subpath exports, environment conditional exports, and module system conditional exports in the same package.json?

Tags: typescript, npm, es6-modules, commonjs

When publishing an NPM package, there are three distinct types of export that you can specify in a `package.json` file.

- [**Subpath Exports**](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-exports)

  This allows you to export multiple ‘indexes’ from a single package, at different paths. For example, this subpath export:

  ```json
  // package.json
  {
    "name": "my-package",
    "exports": {
      "./submodule": "./dist/submodule.js"
    }
  }
  ```

  lets you import that index by writing this:

  ```
  // app.ts
  import submodule from 'my-package/submodule';
  ```
- **Environment [Conditional Exports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#conditional-exports)**

  To target a particular package file to Node, React Native, web browsers, or TypeScript, you can use named conditional exports like this:

  ```json
  // package.json
  {
    "name": "my-package",
    "exports": {
      "browser": "./dist/browser/index.js",
      "node": "./dist/node/index.js",
      "react-native": "./dist/react-native/index.js",
      "types": "./dist/types/index.d.ts"
    }
  }
  ```
- **Module System [Conditional Exports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#conditional-exports)**

  To target a differently built bundle to consumers using CommonJS vs. ES Modules, you can name the package loader in a conditional export like this:

  ```json
  // package.json
  {
    "name": "my-package",
    "exports": {
      "import": "./dist/index.js",
      "require": "./dist/index.cjs"
    }
  }
  ```

How do you combine all three? I want to offer submodule exports, that serve different files based on environment (Node, React Native, browser), depending on the package loader the consumer is using, and I want it to all work with TypeScript definitions.

Comment: Did you read the [*nested conditions*](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#nested-conditions) section and that "*[Conditional exports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#conditional-exports) can also be extended to exports subpaths*"?